# Context in RecyclerView click event not being read

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-context

For some reason, the context in my `RecyclerView` adapter is not being read when trying to apply a click listener to my `RecyclerView` item to start a new activity. `myContext.startActivity(intent)` returns an 'unresolved reference' error. What should it be changed to in order for the context to be read? Do I need to use the context of the view holder or the `TextView` or something else?

> Unresolved reference: myContext

```
class MyAdapter(
        val myContext: Context,
        var listCompany: MutableList<ItemCompany>,
        private val mTwoPane: Boolean,
        private val itemClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter
.CompanyViewHolder>() {

    class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_RVItem)

        fun bind(company: ItemCompany, clickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)
        {
            tvTitle.text = company.companyName

            itemView.setOnClickListener {v ->
                val intent: Intent = when (company.companyName) {
                    v.resources.getString(R.string.bing) -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.bing.com/"))
                    }
                    v.resources.getString(R.string.google) -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"))
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.yahoo.com/"))
                    }
                }
                myContext.startActivity(intent)

                clickListener.onItemClick(company)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(myContext)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false)
        return CompanyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CompanyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = listCompany[holder.adapterPosition]

        holder.tvTitle.text = product.companyName

        holder.bind(product, itemClickListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listCompany.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't start an activity from a context reference. You have to start it from an activity reference. Then the startActivity function will be resolved correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin, nested class is by default static, so its data member and member function can be accessed without creating an object of class. Nested class cannot be able to access the data member of outer class.

Since "myContext" is data member of Outer Class ~ "MyAdapter" that's why it's unresolved in Inner Class.

Comment: So should `myContext` be moved to the inner class?

Comment: You can get context from "itemView.getContext ()" within ViewHolder.